# portable java app with built-in oracle database, instead of whole oracle server needed for database usage

Tags: java, database, oracle

How can i make my app portable and independent( like sort of local oracle database system ) so every user has its own independent database, **and with need only to install that small app that i made for him to use it... without need to install whole oracle database server**. p.s sorry for my english guys i hope you understood me.

recap:

1. i want my users to install only app, and not whole oracle
   database system.
2. i want my databsae to be local, and not global(remote);

at the moment i use oracle database server.. i suppose i will have to transfer my data or to repack it somehow , to achieve that effect... any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need it to be oracle, or would [java db](https://db.apache.org/derby/) be a solution?

Comment: well i did research, few months ago with others (opensource portable database solutions) and im aware that they exists but, since i'm forced to use oracle database for this project of mine, i was curious is it possible to achieve that with oracle?

Comment: What is the problem with installing Oracle on each user's machine. It sounds like that's your *requirement*, not something to be avoided.

Comment: resources.. i don't know if you ever installed oracle database before, but you need extremely many resources to keep things up and running.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not fixed on Oracle there are numerous possibilities:

Check out this SO-Post for a collection: [Alternatives to SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417917/alternatives-to-sqlite)

In addition i would like to throw in [H2DB](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer, well i know that it is possible to achieve that solution with other portable database solutions, but is is possible with oracle as well?